# actionbar logo without label

Tags: android, android-actionbar, label

I wish to use a logo on the actionbar without displaying the application or activity label:

In order to display the app name with the launcher icon and everywhere else the app appears I must use:

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

with the activity containing:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

If I set the application label to `android:label=""`
and or use `setTitle("");` 
after setting the launcher activity label to the app name, the app name is displayed over actionbar logo for a second before being removed.

My question is how can I keep my actionbar logo and app name under the launcher icon but never display the label.

I could use a splash screen and give that activity the

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

attributes but that is a workaround I do not wish to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple solution would be using an empty string resource as the label:

First Create an empty string resource and then replace

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

with

```
 android:label="@string/your_empty_string"
```

Inside AndroidManifest.xml

So the actionbar logo would still display and the title would be empty, without that delay you mentioned in your post when changing the actionbar's title programically.

Comment: I appreciate the response but leaving an empty string resource for the label will leave the app without a name since the LAUNCNHER category and MAIN action need that attribute for the app to have a name everywhere else on the device.